# Vue Components not updating after change in code

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, web, vue-component

It works fine when I use if for the first time after that I need to restart the server to see changes in the component

Comment: Need more information to be able to help. How about including some of the related code in your answer.

Comment: Make sure you're running a dev server and not a production server. Dev servers hot reload, prod servers don't

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm run watch`. This should solve your problem